# Spring Boot 2,.6.9 app fails to start due to in compatibility springCloudVersion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build

As build was failing due to security issues for older version of the Spring Boot, I just upgraded to a higher version of Spring boot 2.6.9 in my build.gradle

plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.9'

ext {
set('springCloudVersion', '2020.0.1')

The above And the original ext dependency was left alone when I upgraded Spring boot version to 2.6.9

So what is the correct version of Spring cloud version for Spring boot 2.6.6? Spring app is failing to start.

Here is the log for startup

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper
at java.base/java. lang. ClassLoader. defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java. lang. ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader. java: 1017)
at java.base/java. security. SecureClassLoader. defineClass(SecureClassLoader. java:174) <5 internal lines>
at java.base/java. lang. ClassLoader. loadClass(ClassLoader. java: 522)
at org. springframework. cloud. bootstrap. encrypt. DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.getTextEncryptor(DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor. java: 82)
at org. springframework. cloud. bootstrap. encrypt. DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment (DecryptEnvironmentPostProcessor. java: 68)
at org. springframework.boot. env. EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener. onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener
.java: 102)
at org. springframework. boot. env. EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener. onApplicationEvent (EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener. java:87)
at org. springframework. context. event. SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster. java: 176)
at org.springframework. context. event. SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster. java: 169)
at org. springframework. context. event. SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster. java: 143)
at org.springframework. context. event. SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org. springframework. boot. context. event. EventPublishingRunListener. environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener. java: 85)
at org. springframework. boot. SpringApplicationRunListeners. lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners, java: 66)
[main] ERROR org. springframework.boot. SpringApplication - Application run failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using Spring Cloud 2021.0. See [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases) for Spring Boot and Spring Cloud compatibility.